# how to get the language of webpage in java

Tags: java, web, jsoup

I am creating an java application in which I want to know the language it is made on (like HTML, php, .net, RDF, Turtle, owl) etc.
I download the source of page from crawler, but cant able to get the language. I am using jsoup to download.

I didn't find the answer

Comment: Because there's no way to know other than educated guessing. But if it's a web page, I think you can safely assume you'll see at least some HTML. At least a couple of the languages you list don't even make sense in this context.

Comment: You might consider the web server version: [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/120783/can-i-detect-what-webserver-a-website-is-using)

Answer (score 1):

There is no foolproof way to do this, but a start would be to look at the URL extension if it has one and use it. If it doesn't have an extension in URL, you could look for a form in the page source and look at its action field maybe that could give you an idea.